# why is video tag of html not working what to do?

Tags: html

hi im using this tag for adding video but its not working

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
```

I have also tried this

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls src="movie.mp">
```

its not working for me , and my browser is avast secure browser

Comment: maybe `.mp` need to be `.mp4`, also try to add a text inside the video like `<video>(previus code) "sorry, video isn't supported"</video>` if it print to you the the text then is the browser.... see this example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: ok i see the problem now , thank you